# Printing from VBA in one print session

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Invoice form in Excel. Same area is used for "Original" and "Copy" of Invoice. In VBA I print preview "Original" then change it to "Copy" and print preview again. Is it possible to Preview them both in one PrintPreview session?

Comment: I think Only if you have them as two pages on the worksheet

Comment: You are right. But I don't want to add new sheet every time, print and delete it afterward. It is a very heavy operation. Thank you anyway. I want to open and close print session by myself. And I will find a way...